# How do you use drupal's devel krumo ddebug_backtrace()?

Tags: views, debugging

I've been trying to debug a weird bug on Drupal 7 for awhile. It happens randomly on my site as it's hard to reproduce. I'm able to finally get `ddebug_backtrace()` to run when the error happens. The error breaks all of my views on the site when it happens and throws the following error:

> Warning: include(/home/xxx/public_html/.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in theme_render_template() (line 1534 of /home/xxx/public_html/includes/theme.inc).

It's complaining that `theme_render_template()` can't find a template file as the variable given to the function is just .tpl.php.

I'm able to insert an if statement when this happens within that function as this:

```
  if($template_file == '.tpl.php') {
    ddebug_backtrace();
    print_r('<pre>xxxx');
    print_r('TEMPLATE FILE: ');
      print_r($template_file);
    print_r('</pre>');
  }
```

I'm able to get the debug output in krumo as shown below. I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for. I just understand that each numbered line represents where that function was called within that order. But what I'm trying to look for is a blank variable of some sort which makes it output .tpl.php to give such an error.

Judging from the output, the culprit is the Views module, but I'm not sure where. What should I be looking for exactly?

[image]

Comment: Digging into the code, you're looking for the reason why the hook info array returned from the theme registry has an empty `template` key when the render function is invoked from `theme()`. Don't worry about `theme_register_template()`, that's irrelevant - it's just working with what it's given. Go to /devel/php, run `dpm(theme_get_registry(FALSE));`, and look for entries that match up with items in the args array to `theme()` (`views_view` etc). If any of those have an empty `template`, that's what's causing the problem

Comment: thanks clive. just did a dpm(theme_get_registry(FALSE)); and it return an empty array on the dpm output: http://prntscr.com/b3pm2r

Comment: Oh right it's not an array is it - try `foreach (theme_get_registry(true) as $item) { if (isset($item['template']) && empty($item['template'])) { dpm($item); } }`, that'll dump out any item that has a template key with an empty value

Comment: Er no, wrong again, just try `dpm(theme_get_registry(true));`

Comment: Ok i was able to get an output when set to true. It spit out a 562 element array and I clicked on each one then did a search for **0 characters* to see if it highlighted anything on the page and it didnt. http://prntscr.com/b3rr5s --- i tried to just read the ddbacktrace() function, but I can't pinpoint when does it set the blank variable that causes it to output an empty .tpl.php.

Comment: omg... soo close.. =D ... http://prntscr.com/b3s3yu --- i was able to trace it back by detecting the empty $template_file in the theme() function. http://prntscr.com/b3s3yu -- $template_file is assigned from $info variable and the $info variable is formed using $hook variable. which leads me now to a *ds_extras_preprocess_view_layout* function.... hmmm im not too sure what setting in ds_extras is causing this issue. but at least i got this far.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was quite annoying to solve. What I did was:

- Isolate the variable that was causing the issue.
- Setup a conditional to detect this variable when it happens.
- Add drupal's ddebug_backtrace() to the conditional.
- Trace back to where the function was being called up.
- Find out how that problematic variable is being passed in.
- Keep following the backtrace to the point where that variable is assigned and not just passed along to another function. In my case it was in theme() that assigned the blank variable *$template_file*.
- From there I needed to know when theme() was being called. The original backtrace didn't leave any clues to which module was calling it aside from views, but views gets called all over the place. Now I needed to find the module that was calling views.
- In theme() there were a bunch of hook variables that gave the hint of where it was coming from. I dpm() all the $hook and $hooks variables and it showed the error was happening when a "display suite" hook was being called.
- In the end all I needed to do was uncheck this box. I still don't know why it caused the issue randomly... -_-

[image]

My debug code to get the output I needed:
[image]

Comment: Strange, I have that box checked on a website and it works flawless. It could have been your PHP ran out of memory (this is often a cause of strange and inconsistent behavior). You could try to increase the memory limit in your php.ini file and see if it still happens. On the other hand if you do not need the functions provided by the checkbox, leave it like this :)

Comment: seems like its not that box after all. the errors came back after using the site for some time. I was able to debug it a bit further. It seems that the theme registry is missing the "views_view" array when this bug happens, but when it is working that array exists. I'm not sure where to look now.